# Contact Card information in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, contacts

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013 Plan 1.

I asked (mainly) about the presence indicators in Sharepoint Online 2013 some time ago in here: [Sharepoint Online Presence and Contact Cards](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111105/sharepoint-online-presence-and-contact-cards). But as I had a question regarding more about the contact information rather than presence, I decided to make a new question. :)

Anyways, is there a way to show information (Name, Department, Title, Phone, email..) and user profile picture in the hover/pop-up Contact Card that shows when hovering mouse over a linked name of a user? At the moment in our SPO intranet we can see the hover/pop-up Contact cards when hovering over the user names but all the information there is to be seen is their username (=email) and nothing else, no picture or name or anything.

As I learned in the question I linked above, presence indicators need Lync to work so does the Contact Card information need it also? Seems a bit ridiculous to have such a cool Contact Card feature in Sharepoint if it can't get profile info from user MySite for example.

Thanks! :)